# Code refactoring HTML

Tags: html, css

I have written this messy html, was wondering what could be the good way of refactoring this code?

```
<div id="budget" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" name="total_budget" class="input-large budget_inside" placeholder="Total project budget targets"/>
  <input type="text" name="annual_budget" class="input-large budget_inside" placeholder="Annual budget targets"/>
  <input type="text" name="domestic_travel" class="input-large budget_inside" style="display:block" placeholder="Domestic Travel"/>
  <textarea rows="8" name="domestic_description" class="span5" style="margin-top:10px" placeholder="If Domestic Travel amount present then specify the meetings or conferences you will attend."></textarea>
</div>
```

There are 30 such inputs, is there any better way of solving it?

Comment: There are 30 such inputs, is there any better way of solving it?

Comment: Your HTML looks fine. Not sure what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: should I put class for all inner tag inside budget div? or should I individually put class inside inner elements?

Comment: Is the question about how to style the inputs without duplicating the class on each one?

Comment: If on the whole it looks correct than yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is "How to target all the text inputs in my `budget` div", then that could be done like this:

```
#buget input[type=text] {
    /* insert style here */
}
```

That would *marginally* simplify your HTML to:

```
<div id="budget" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="total_budget" placeholder="Total project budget targets"/>
    <input type="text" name="annual_budget" placeholder="Annual budget targets"/>
    <input type="text" name="domestic_travel" style="display:block" placeholder="Domestic Travel"/>
    <textarea rows="8" name="domestic_description" class="span5" style="margin-top:10px" placeholder="If Domestic Travel amount present then specify the meetings or conferences you will attend."></textarea>
</div>
```

You may want to also remove the inline style from the `textarea`

Comment: I ended up solving with  $('#budget input[type=text]').addClass('input-large budget_inside');